# pyspark returns a no module named error for a custom module

Tags: python, pyspark

I would like to import a .py file that contains some modules. I have saved the files **init**.py and util_func.py under this folder:

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/myutil

The util_func.py contains all the modules that i would like to use. I also need to create a pyspark udf so I can use it to transform my dataframe. My code looks like this:

```
import myutil
from myutil import util_func
myudf = pyspark.sql.functions.udf(util_func.ConvString, StringType())
```

somewhere down the code, I am using this to convert one of the columns in my dataframe:

```
df = df.withColumn("newcol", myudf(df["oldcol"]))
```

then I am trying to see if it converts it my using:

```
df.head()
```

It fails with an error "No module named myutil".

I am able to bring up the functions within ipython. Somehow the pyspark engined does not see the module. Any idea how to make sure that the pyspark engine picks up the module?

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: is myutil.py present in the current dir or in environment or a package in the environment?

Comment: it is present under /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/.  Also I am using python 3.4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must build a egg file of your package using setup tools and add the egg file to your application like below

```
sc.addFile('<path of the egg file>')
```

here `sc` is the spark context variable.

Comment: instead of addfile, i used sc.addpyfile. I didnt have to add the package to the setup tools. After importing the module, I initialized the sc with addpyfile and then it was able to use the modules. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I found the point! Spark UDF uses another executor when you have a problem like yours, the environment variables are different!

My case, I was developing, debugging and testing on Zeppelin and it has two different interpreters for Python and Spark! When I install the libs in the terminal, I could use the functions normally but on UDF not!

Solution: Just set the same environment for driver and executor, `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_PYTHON`

Comment: How is this done? "set the same environment for driver and executor, PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON and PYSPARK_PYTHON"

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for hijack the thread. I want to reply to @rouge-one comment but I dont have enough reputation to do it

I'm having the same problem with OP but this time the module is not a single py file but the annoy spotify package in Python https://github.com/spotify/annoy/tree/master/annoy

I tried `sc.addPyFile('venv.zip')` and added `--archives ./venv.zip#PYTHON \` in the spark-submit file 
but it still threw the same error message

I can still use `from annoy import AnnoyIndex` in the spark submit file but everytime I try to import it in the udf like this

```
    schema = ArrayType(StructType([
        StructField("char", IntegerType(), False),
        StructField("count", IntegerType(), False)
    ]))

    f= 128

    def return_candidate(x):
      from annoy import AnnoyIndex
      from pyspark import SparkFiles
      annoy = AnnoyIndex(f)
      annoy.load(SparkFiles.get("annoy.ann"))
      neighbor = 5
      annoy_object = annoy.get_nns_by_item(x,n = neighbor, include_distances=True)
      return annoy_object


    return_candidate_udf = udf(lambda y: return_candidate(y), schema )
inter4 =inter3.select('*',return_candidate_udf('annoy_id').alias('annoy_candidate_list'))
```