# ModuleNotFoundError while using geodesic in udf pyspark function

Tags: python, pyspark, module, geopy

We have pyspark dataframe like:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(['target'], [2], [2], [3], [3]), (['NJ'],[3],[3], [4], [4]), (['target', 'target'],[4,5], [4,5], [6,7], [6,7]), (['CA'],[5],[5], [6], [6]), ], ('group_name', 'long', 'lat','com_long','com_lat'))
```

[Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4dfu.png)

We want to extract the data at the position of **target** and use it to perform a distance calculation with a **udf function**.

First we want to get the index of the target position in the group_name column.

```
df = df.withColumn("target-1a-idx", (F.array_position(df.group_name, "target") -1 )) 
df = df.withColumn("target-1a-idx",F.when(F.col("target-1a-idx")!=-1,F.col("target-1a-idx")))
```

Now we create the helper columns with the target index.

```
columns = ['long', 'lat','com_long','com_lat']
for col in columns:
    df = df.withColumn(
        prefix + col, F.col(col)[F.col("target-1a-idx")])
```

[DF with helper columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crrcX.png)

Filtering the Null values is optional.

```
df_filtered = df.filter(F.col("target-1a-idx").isNotNull())
```

Finally we defined a udf function to calculate distance, and called it

```
import geopy
from geopy.distance import geodesic

@F.udf(returnType=T.FloatType())
def geodesic_udf(a, b):
    if (a is None) | (b is None):
        return 1.0
    else:
        return geodesic(a, b).meters

df_filtered = df_filtered.withColumn(
    "distance_to_station",
    geodesic_udf(
        F.array("target_long", "target_lat"),
        F.array(
            "target_com_long",
            "target_com_lat",
        ),
    ),
)
```

`

**ERROR MESSAGE**

While we are absolutely sure that we installed and imported geopy and geodesic correctly, we **recieved ModuleNotFoundError**. We guess the problem is actually not with the module.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopy'

[This is the error message:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JeAa.png)

Could you help us with the answer. Thank you!

Checked imports and installed packages (pip list). And filtered Nulls.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: maybe this could be the issue
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68899970/1415826

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the use of the nodes. The library is not installed in the node. Using a udf does not use sparklogik but python and would need the library on each node.

-> If possible, do not use a udf but a pyspark/spark native function.

def calc_distance(df, suffix, lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2):

```
#Haversine formula to calculate the distance between two gps coordinates and return the calculated result as Spark dataframe definition.

df = df.withColumn('haversine_d{sf}'.format(sf=suffix), (F.pow(F.sin(F.radians(F.col(lat2) - F.col(lat1)) / 2), 2) +
                                       F.cos(F.radians(F.col(lat1))) * F.cos(F.radians(F.col(lat2))) *
                                       F.pow(F.sin(F.radians(F.col(lon2) - F.col(lon1)) / 2), 2)))
df = df.withColumn('distance_in_m{sf}'.format(sf=suffix), F.atan2(F.sqrt(F.col('haversine_d{sf}'.format(sf=suffix))), F.sqrt(-F.col('haversine_d{sf}'.format(sf=suffix)) + 1)) * 12742000)
df = df.drop('haversine_d{sf}'.format(sf=suffix))
return df
```

or

-> run the environment on each node. Description [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Running-PySpark-with-Conda-Env/ta-p/247551)

---

p.s. I am part of the team asking the question.